# WordPress Search on pluign page

Tags: wordpress

I have an plugin to didsplay list of coupon code in WordPress. I would like to place search box for searching coupon code in coupon page.

```
                <form method="get" id="searchform" action="">
                    <input type="text" value="Search" name="s" id="s" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="5" />
                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
                </form>
```

When I click on search button it redirect me to wordpress post page instead of plugin default page.

Suggest me working solution for implement searching in plugin page.

Comment: No one have any solution regarding search in custom post types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to redirect it manually using this form:

```
<form  method="get" action="<?php echo "edit.php?";?>"  id="coupon">
                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="tag-search-input">Search Coupon Code:</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="wpsc-product" /> //required to redirect it coupon page
                     <input type="hidden" name="page" value="wpsc-edit-coupons" />//required to redirect it coupon page
                    <input type="search" id="search-input" name="s" value="">
                    <input type="submit" name="" id="submit" class="button" value="Search Coupon Code">
                    </form>
```

After this you will have to grape the result from $_GET['s'] and apply manual search on that file.